# Importing a lot of modules from custom package

Tags: python, import, module, package

Say i have this this structure.

```
MyApp
├── main.py
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    ├── c.py
    ├── d.py
    ├── e.py
    ├── f.py
    ├── g.py
    ├── h.py
    ├── ...
    └── z.py
```

And in `main.py` I need to use all modules, from `a.py` to `z.py`

I'd like to know how I can import all those modules with one import statement.

So instead of doing

```
from package import a
from package import b
...
from package import z
```

I could just import the package and have all the modules ready.

**Things I've tried**

```
import package
a = package.a.A()
# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Now I know I could put a code in `__init__.py` to add all the modules to `__all__`, but from what I've read, we should avoid 'from package import *'

The reason for this is that the package might have an increasing number of modules and I would like to adding an import statement to the main code each time a module is created. Ideally I'd like to be able to just drop the module in the package and have it ready for use.

Comment: You can also look at the `__all__` variable [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python), maybe you can use it in your `__init__.py`

Comment: @Amr this allow you to `from package import *` to get all the packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `__init__.py`, you can:

```
import a, b, c, d...
```

and then the modules will be placed in the `package` namespace after you do `import package`.

You you really want to names `a`, `b`, etc. in main.py's namespace, and have this happen with no effort, you can't really avoid `from package import *`; any other method of importing them all implicitly is going to be just as bad, since it involves polluting the namespace with names you don't explicitly import.

Comment: But i still wouldn't be able to just drop a module in the package directory and have it just work. Doing this way is a little different than doing 'from package import a' in main.py. Unless of course, i automate it, which is what im going to attempt right now. thanks for this.

Comment: Do you have a use case for having names injected into the main script's namespace that you don't even know about when writing the script?

Comment: @lyrae the main difference is that you'd have to add the import once (in your package), instead of having to do all those imports in all applications using that package.

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is very bad design practice since you import all but not what is required. In general IT SLOWS DOWN program loading - never do it if not really required. Never initialize not used variables in modules also since it waste of time.

Two solution which not follow the good design practice if not used correctly.

Check this answer [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python).

You could also use `__import__` to load modules and `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to list all files names in directory and load as modules.

BTW this pattern is lead to serious security holes since you allow load anything - it need only creation permission to break security.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. The thing is, all modules will always be used by the main program.

Comment: If you program always will use 100% of modules and has single run it is good pattern. Avoid it if you have even 100% cover since load on require is faster and eco than load all at once.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend **not** doing this. If you must, this is the method I've used in the past:

```
# __init__.py

import os
import re

PACKAGE = 'MyApp.package'
MODULE_RE = r"^.*.py$"

for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
  if not re.match(MODULE_RE, filename) or filename == "__init__.py":
    continue

  imported_module = __import__('%s.%s' % (PACKAGE, filename[:-3]),
                               {}, {},
                               filename[:-3])
```

Comment: I'd use the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) for matching module filenames here instead of a regular expression. Even an `.endswith('.py')` would be better..

Answer (score 1):

This code is not very beautiful, but I think it is a nice workaround

```
import os

for i in os.listdir('package'):
    if i.endswith('.py') and not i.startswith('__'):
        exec('from package import ' + i[:-3])
```

Comment: Better is to use __import__ as explained in another answer and little fix filter on names.

Comment: And @Chameleon meant `__import__` of course, the `__` double underscore got interpreted as bold by SO there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I understood that. This answer was just a simple thought of me, and at that time there were no other answers. But you're right, `__import__` is probably better (but this is simpler :D)